# Assign results of request in variable inside .then at fetch is not holding the val

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm learning about how use API's and building some apps with this but when I try to assign a request results into a variable, when i print in console the variable is blank.

Can someone help me?

## HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>MOVIES</h1>
        <div class="input__container">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="search__icon">
                search
            </span>
            <input type="text" name="" id="searchInput" class="searchMovie" placeholder="Search" (change)="movieSearch()">
            <div class="searchSuggestion" >
                <ul id="suggestionList"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="movies__container">
        @for (movie of topMovies; track $index) {
            <movie-card [movie]="movie"></movie-card>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

## JS

```
movieSearch(){
var suggestions: any[] = []
const div = document.getElementById("suggestionList")!
const input = \<HTMLInputElement\>document.getElementById("searchInput")
console.log(input.value)

    fetch(environment.queryByName + `&query=${input.value}`, environment.options)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
      suggestions = data.results
      //console.log(suggestions) //Here the value is assign
    })
    
    console.log(suggestions) //Here the value is blank
    
    for(var i = 0; i < suggestions.length; i++){
      const node = document.createElement("li")
      const text = document.createTextNode(suggestions[i].title)
      node.appendChild(text)
      div.appendChild(node)
    }

}
```